# MongoDB 2.2.5 upgrade issue with special character in db name

Tags: mongodb

I just upgraded to 2.2.5 version. My old data with 2.0.2 had database name with special character : in the name.
After upgrade, when I am fetching data from that db, I am getting following error

assertion 16256 Invalid ns [bcxb:queryTest.system.namespaces] ns:bcxb:queryTest.system.namespaces

This is happening for all m database name having special character :
Please help.

Comment: There are certain reserved characters now, can't you rename the databases? You can also use getSiblingDb() most likely

Comment: No, I cant rename my db. Tried getSiblingDB, but didn't work...

Comment: Looks like `:` is prohibited in database names, but only on Windows because the FAT32 file system doesn't support it.  See [this comment](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9309?focusedCommentId=311267&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-311267) in Jira.